# BIztalk - keeping a session key in an API

Tags: wcf, session, biztalk, svc, send-port

I have an API that has port type with multiple functions.
From those functions I need the logging operation and synchronize operation. 
The problem is that BizTalk doesn't save session from the logging operation and thus not allowing me to perform the synchronize operation.

the API in question is a SVC WS which I generated from WCF consume adapter.

Does anyone has an idea how can I achieve the synchronize operation to work in the same session of the logging operation.

p.s.

The Logging operation doesn't return a session key it's returning only a status code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that scenario is not supported by BizTalk Server, at least with the our of the box bindings.

All Send Operations are sessionless.

But, there are several ways to maintain a session.  Ask the service provider how they're doing it and there might be a way to replicate that with BizTalk.

Comment: I have a testing tool and there it works. so how can I replicate that code in biztalk? there I'm doing the logging operation and then moving on to a switch case which goes to the synchronize operation I need. so is there a way to do it?

Comment: I mean exactly how are they maintaining the state?  Cookies?  You need to know that before working on how to do it in BizTalk.